# EE1 to EE2 upgrade - freeform form builder addon

Tags: expressionengine

I've got a site that i've been tasked with upgrading from EE1.6.8 to EE 2.5.3. At this point I've upgraded to 1.7.3 and am ready for the big jump to 2.5.3.

I've got info on how to migrate the ngen file fields and matrix with ngen file field so I'm fine there. I'm also prepared for the structure portion of the upgrade. The issue is that the site is using an add-on which no longer exists to power a form builder. It's using [Freeform Data Select](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/freeform-data-select) - The closest thing for EE2 that I've been able to find is [Low Freeform Field](http://gotolow.com/addons/low-freeform-field/docs).

My question is this. Is it possible to convert the field type such that all existing forms (10+ with about 20+ fields in each form) will carry over and continue to receive data? Has anyone done this? Any recommendations on how to proceed or things to look out for that I should be aware of?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, so most EE fieldtypes store their value directly in the `exp_channel_data` table. After looking at both of those fields, they store the exact same thing---the Freeform field name. So, that means that they should be able to be used interchangeably and you probably don't need to do anything aside from upgrading as is and then installing Low's field type and switching the field's actual type in the EE admin.

As always, backup your database before taking a chance, but I think this particular part of your upgrade should be fairly straightforward.

Comment: This is what I was hoping to hear. Just getting all my ducks in a row as this is a really large site with so many potential break points.